# Invisible button (using pack_forget) still occupies space

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I use pack_forget() to make a button invisible. But when i subsequently create a label, it appears bellow the invisible button. How can i avoid this displacement?

The following sample code demonstrates the issue:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def secondwidget(self):
        self.b.pack_forget()
        self.l = Label(text="Lowered Label :(")
        self.l.pack()

    def firstwidget(self):
        self.b = Button(self)
        self.b["text"] = "Button"
        self.b["command"] = self.secondwidget
        self.b.pack()

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.firstwidget()

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

EDIT: I use python 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set parent for label:

```
self.l = Label(text="Lowered Label :(")
print(self.l.winfo_parent() == str(self))
>>> False
```

Compare:

```
self.b = Button(self)
print(self.b.winfo_parent() == str(self))
>>> True
```

Comment: How do i set the parent for label?

Comment: `Label(self, ...)` - first argument is parent for new widget. `self.b = Button(self)`

Comment: tkinter has some bugs. Maybe this can be useful for you: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/1999-July/017588.html